# Access a nested UserControl's ContentPresenter with Blend

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I've created a simple UserControl in Blend which contains (amongst other things) a ContentPresenter.

I'd like to be able to drop this UserControl onto another UserControl and then add other controls into its ContentPresenter, but when I include it in the second UserControl I can't see a way to do this.

Using Blend, how do I expose the underlying ContentPresenter so that its contents can be set visually (ie: so they appear as child controls in the Objects and Timeline window)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it’s a content control, to add child controls you set them as the content of the control

```
<MyContentControl>
    <Grid x:Name=”ImAChild”>
    </Grid>
</MyContentControl>
```

Edit: now that I think about it you might need to do something to make the Content property the default property which is populated by the inner xaml of your control, I can't remember exactly what it was but if your xaml looks like this (below) it doesn't matter anyway

```
<MyContentControl>
    <MyContentControl.Content>
        <Grid x:Name=”ImAChild”>
        </Grid>
    </MyContentControl.Content>
</MyContentControl>
```

Edit2
Your `MyUserControl` would need a `MyContent` property of type `object` and it'd have to somehow display the value of that property. You might be able to create it in the setter of the MyContent property but it seems "hacky"

```
<MyUserControl>
    <MyUserControl.MyContent>
        <Grid x:Name=”ImAChild”>
        </Grid>
    </MyContentControl.MyContent>
</MyUserControl>
```

Comment: It's a user control rather than a content control... does it need to be a content control in order to do this?

Comment: If I nest it like the first example then the entire contents get replaced by the `ImAChild` grid. The second sounds like it's along the right lines though... i'll give it a try shortly.

Comment: It's probably easier to just create a first class control that extends ContentControl, you can probably work it using an extra property on your UserControl and binding your ContentPresenter to it's value but it might not work and might be a faf around. See Edit2.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and extended ContentControl in the end, then just copied the template from my UserControl into an implicit style for my ContentControl type.  That works, cheers :)

Comment: UserControl is a ContentControl

Comment: A little late to the party Grokodile but better late than never :)